# Is there a simple, plaintext, lightweight hosted web-based text editor?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, cloud

I want to host it on my own Ubuntu Server, access it from outside within my browser and be able to edit my notes in it and it will save. I also want to be able to access it from a smartphone's web browser and make edits to my notes.

Anything like this available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [web-notetaker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/web-notetaker/) or a wiki. If those do not have the features you want, explain what they lack.

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried DokuWiki which was very easy to set up. It does what I need. It lets me connect to it over the web from any device, edit my notes, and save it. It's also hosted by myself. But even a wiki is a bit much for my needs. Is there something similar (self-hosted, online-accessible), but is just a plain and simple note-taking web-based interface? Very ultra lightweight? I just want to take notes but host the note myself.

Comment: sum2000 had a few suggestions and a wiki link. I do not know about your mobile device, but I personally use ssh. winscp allows edits over ssh in windows, you can do edits over ssh with vim or gvim as well.  `vim scp://user@server//full_path/to/document`

Comment: Thanks both. DokuWiki is brilliant and quite simple. I like the way a wiki page is a simple text file on the filesystem which I can edit.

Comment: glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

http://gpl.internetconnection.net/vi/

It is online clone of popular VI editor that should run in most javascript enabled browsers. It's called jsvi, and now you can write your own programs and HTML code from anywhere!

On a more serious note, the Vi simulator works with nearly all the traditional keys and substitution commands, and you can copy/paste from the clipboard. It also includes a built-in spell checker for those long-night moments when you've stared a word for too long and can no longer remember how to spell it. Does that happen to other people, or is it just us?

if you want more chechout this link 
http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-useful-online-code-editors